# HTTP POST from Android not return data when response size big

Tags: java, android, servlets

I have a problem when fire a POST request to server and after process server response result but when server write data sometime data can't transfer to client, dead at writer.write() function. 
I use Apache Tomcat to deploy app, each time server need response about 7m data before gzip and 300k after gzip

Please Help !

my code:

```
protected void dispatch(JSONObject request,
              Map<String, FormDataItem> formItems,
              HttpServletRequest servletRequest,
              HttpServletResponse servletResponse, SecurityToken token,
              String callback) throws JSONException, IOException {
        long timeGetData = 0;
        long begin = System.currentTimeMillis();

        String key = null;

        if (request.has("id")) {
              key = request.getString("id");
        }

        // getRpcHandler never returns null
        Future<?> future = getHandler(request, servletRequest).execute(
                    formItems, token, jsonConverter);

        timeGetData = System.currentTimeMillis();
        // Resolve each Future into a response.
        ResponseItem response = getResponseItem(future);
        ResponseItem responseTemp = (ResponseItem) response.getResponse();

        // Generate the output
        Writer writer = servletResponse.getWriter();

        if ("syndata.getAllDataFromServer".equals(request.getString("method"))) {
              if (responseTemp.getErrorCode() == 200) {
                    SynDataObject outObject = (SynDataObject) (responseTemp
                                .getResponse());
                    writer.write(jsonConverter.convertToString(outObject
                                .getParams()));
                    writer.write("\r\n");

                    for (int i = 0; i < outObject.getListTableData().size(); i++) {
                          TableDataObject subData = outObject.getListTableData().get(
                                      i);
                          int subDataLength = subData.getData().size();
                          int currentFarm = 0;
                          int factor = 1000;
                          int lastIndex = 0;

                          while (lastIndex < subDataLength) {
                                if ((currentFarm * factor + factor) > subDataLength) {
                                      lastIndex = (factor * currentFarm)
                                                  + (subDataLength - (factor * currentFarm));
                                } else {
                                      lastIndex = (factor * currentFarm) + factor;
                                }

                                TableDataObject chilData = new TableDataObject();
                                chilData.setTableName(subData.getTableName());
                                chilData.setTableColumns(subData.getTableColumns());
                                chilData.setPkField(subData.getPkField());

                                 chilData.setData(subData.getData().subList(
                                            currentFarm * factor, lastIndex));


                                writer.write(jsonConverter.convertToString(chilData));
                                writer.write("\r\n");
                                writer.flush();

                                ++currentFarm;
                          }
                    }
              } else {
                    Object result = getJSONResponse(key, response);
                    String content = jsonConverter.convertToString(result);

                    if (callback != null) {
                          writer.write(callback);
                          writer.write('(');
                    }

                    writer.write(content);

                    if (callback != null) {
                          writer.write(");\n");
                    }
              }
        } else {
              Object result = getJSONResponse(key, response);
              String content = jsonConverter.convertToString(result);

              if (callback != null) {
                    writer.write(callback);
                    writer.write('(');
              }

              writer.write(content);

              if (callback != null) {
                    writer.write(");\n");
              }
        }

  }
```

Comment: Can you please append the error you are getting (stacktrace etc.). For this you may edit your original post and add the information.

Comment: @HeikoRupp  it's just deadlock and waiting a long time but didn't getting any error :(

Answer (score 0):

Each browser has some request timeout value.
If the time taken to serve the request or the time taken to reach the writer.write() line exceeds, the client connection gets closed.

So u won't be able to write any info to writer.

Comment: i request from Android client Munesh :)